# c# mashal const std::list<object> from c++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, dllimport

I have to use a c++ DLL in c# and I have to import in my c# program this function defined in the c++ DLL:

```
void rtdGetSkillsetListResult(bool success, const std::list <skillset_info> skillsetList)
```

How can I "translate" in c#

```
const std::list <skillset_info>
```

where skillset_info has defined in c++ dll with the following structure:

```
struct skillset_info
{
   std::string code;
   bool standby; 
};
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed C# code cannot consume unmanaged C++ objects like `std::list`. So you cannot use the unmanaged DLL directly from C#.

The simplest solution will be to make a C++/CLI layer that adapts from unmamaged to managed.

Another option would be to adapt the unmamaged code so that it was callable with p/invoke but I think that would involve more effort than C++/CLI.

Comment: Thanks a lot David! I'll make a C++/CLI Layer.